# Eval check for DBNull doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

```
<%# Eval("Description") == DBNull.Value ? "empty" : "notempty"%>
```

is showing always 'notempty' even there is null in that field in DB (type of varchar(), null)
...
Tried also checking for empty string:

```
<%# Eval("Description") == "" ? "empty" : "notempty"%>
```

and it always displays notempty... what's wrong here??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a difference between `DBNull.Value` and `null`. It is possible the field is returning `null`.

Try

```
<%# Eval("Description") == null ? "empty" : "notempty"%>
```

Also if the field value type is supposed to be string you could do something along the lines of..

```
<%# (Eval("Description") as string) ?? "empty" %>
```

Comment: this worked, can you explain me shortly what's the difference ? Thanks !!

Comment: @Stewie Griffin I think the most basic way to explain it is db values vs .net values. Basically `DBNull.Value` indicates missing database values, where as `null` indicates data that is `null`.

Comment: @QuintinRobinson there is a difference between Null and DBNull.  Remember that most SQL engines have at minimum a 3-state value system; where as .Net is based on a 2-state value system.  Even the Nullable Generic is more of a wrapper than anything else.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using this method:

```
<%# Convert.IsDBNull(Eval("Description") ? "empty" : "notempty"%>
```

Comment: Combine this pattern with a `String.IsNullOrWhitespace()` and the solution is sound

Answer (score 4):

It is not actually storing `DBNull` at this level.  You need to look for `null` or an empty string which `string.IsNullOrEmpty` should be enough and will capture both states of `null` and empty.

```
<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Description").ToString()) ? "empty" : "notempty"%>
```

Comment: it will be a null reference error if description is null.ToString()