# C# Error with if statement using Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net

I’m getting an error when I try to do something like this below,

```
<% if (Eval("DescriptionShort") == "")
    { %>
    There is no description for this winery
<%}
    { %>
    <%# Eval("DescriptionShort") %>
<%}%>
```

The error I’m getting is,

**Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.**

Am I able to do something like this? If not can I do something in the code behind with this?

```
SqlDataAdapter adDetail = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TBLWineries WHERE WineryShow = 'True' AND WineryRegionFK =" + Request["WineryRegionID"], conn);

DataSet dsDetail = new DataSet();
adDetail.Fill(dsDetail);
```

**Edit**

It's a DataList with a table inside, I need that for the layout of the page. The next two lines of code show how I populate the DataList,

```
WineryListDL.DataSource = dsDetail;
WineryListDL.DataBind();
```

Someone elsewhere said I could use this, it doesn't give an error it doesn't display the else part! if "DescriptionShort" exists it works fine but if not I get no text.

```
<%# Eval("DescriptionShort") == "" ? "There is no description for this winery" : Eval("DescriptionShort") %>
```

Should that work, if so, it may be something to do with "DescriptionShort" not being null or ""???

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do exactly as error said - use some sort of databound control e.g. GridView.
For example bind your dataset to `GridView.DataSource` property and use Eval function to provide values for cells.

Take a look at this MSDN article [Data-Binding Expressions Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx)
And this is example how to use GidView and SqlDataAdapter together: [How to Edit,Update,Delete in Gridview](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/643-how-to-editupdatedelete-gridview.aspx)

Comment: Probably your new problem described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224264/eval-check-for-dbnull-doesnt-work