# Method call on object does NOT throw exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

These days I am running into [many strange scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306275/datatype-returned-varies-based-on-data-in-table) :-)

I have tested the following two codes in ASP.Net application. Code 1 throws exception (as expected) whereas Code 2 does not throw exception (contrary to expectation) when the string value is null.

1. Why is “**EVAL**” not throwing exception in this case?
2. Will EVAL work always like this (i.e.,  “no exception”)  or is it just a luck?
3. Is there any MSDN reference that says 'Eval' returns empty string?

//**Code 1**: Causes Exception

```
 string test = Convert.ToString(subscriber.EncryptedSSN).Substring(0, Convert.ToString(subscriber.EncryptedSSN).Length >= 5 ? 5 : Convert.ToString(subscriber.EncryptedSSN).Length);
```

// **Code 2**: Does not throw Exception

```
 <%# Convert.ToString(Eval("EncryptedSSN")).Substring(0, Convert.ToString(Eval("EncryptedSSN")).Length  >= 5 ? 5 : Convert.ToString(Eval("EncryptedSSN")).Length)  %>
```

**References**:

1. [Eval check for DBNull doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224264/eval-check-for-dbnull-doesnt-work)
2. [Convert.ToString behaves differently for "NULL object" and "NULL string"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514337/convert-tostring-behaves-differently-for-null-object-and-null-string)
3. [Datatype returned varies based on data in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306275/datatype-returned-varies-based-on-data-in-table)

Comment: It would really help if you could come up with a *shorter* example - ideally in a standalone console app. I have no idea what `Eval` even *is* here...

Comment: @JonSkeet I have added ASP.Net tag and updated the question

Comment: I strongly assume that Eval returns `string.Empty` instead of `null`.

Answer (score 6):

Your scenario appears to be incorrect. The first does not give an exception for me on .NET 4:

```
object foo = null;

string test = Convert.ToString(foo).Substring(0, Convert.ToString(foo).Length >= 5 ? 5 : Convert.ToString(foo).Length);
```

This is because `Convert.ToString()` [returns *"The string representation of value, or String.Empty if value is null"*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh.aspx).

String.Empty is not null, it is a string of length 0, so it will not throw an exception when a method is called on it.

A bit of searching led me to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx), explaining databinding in ASP in general, and it explains that *"At run time, the Eval method calls the Eval method of the DataBinder object"*. [`DataBinder.Eval()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx) returns an object, so `Convert.ToString(Eval(Something))` will at least return `String.Empty`, thus not throwing a NullReferenceException if you try to access its result's members or properties.

Comment: Try with "string foo" instead of "object foo"

Comment: @Lijo that is not a "strange scenario" as you call it, it is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a2xyyx8.aspx): _"`Convert.ToString(String)` Returns the specified string instance; no actual conversion is performed"_. If you pass it `null`, it will return `null` and hence the exception will occur. Now that you know this, I hope you can see why a NullReferenceException occurs, what you can do to prevent it and why the `Eval()` one doesn't throw an exception (it must be returning a non-null string, or a non-string value or object).

Comment: Is there any MSDN reference that says `Eval` returns empty string?

Answer (score 1):

What does your `Eval` evaluate to? Maybe it is `String.Empty` instead of null and in that case you won't get the exception.