# Convert.ToString behaves differently for "NULL object" and "NULL string"

Tags: c#

I have foo (`object`) and foo2 (`string`) in  a C# console application. The Code 2 throws exception while Code 1 works fine.

Can you please explain why it is behaving so (with MSDN reference)?

// Code 1

```
object foo = null;
string test = Convert.ToString(foo).Substring(0, Convert.ToString(foo).Length >= 5 ? 5 : Convert.ToString(foo).Length);
```

// Code 2

```
string foo2 = null;
string test2 = Convert.ToString(foo2).Substring(0, Convert.ToString(foo2).Length >= 5 ? 5 : Convert.ToString(foo2).Length);
```

Comment: _"Can you please explain why it is behaving so (with MSDN reference)?"_ - [I just did that on your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513961/method-call-on-null-object-does-not-throw-exception/13514155#comment18498922_13514155).

Comment: @CodeCaster I am sorry. I was not able to understand that from your explanation.

Comment: No problem, you could've commented on my comment, but now you've got your answer anyway. ;-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From the documentation of [`Convert.ToString(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a2xyyx8.aspx):

> **Return Value**
>   Type: `System.String`
>   *value* is returned unchanged.

So `null` input will result in a `null` return value.

From the documentation of [`Convert.ToString(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh.aspx):

> **Return Value**
>   Type: `System.String`
>   The string representation of *value*, or `String.Empty` if *value* is null.

(Where "Nothing" means "null" here.)

So `null` input will result in an empty string (non-null reference) return value.

Comment: @Lijo: Yes, these are in fact two different methods, not one that behaves differently. Methods in the same type (e.g. class) having the same name but different parameter lists are said to be overloaded. See [Member Overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229029(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: `..or String.Empty if value is Nothing.` is replaced by `..or String.Empty if value is null.` by the way `:)`

Comment: @SonerGönül: Thanks - looks like MSDN is now context-sensitive not just for the code snippet, but also that sort of documentation. Interesting.

Comment: Thanks... but this is somewhat strange.

Answer (score 5):

Because:

This is implementation of Convert.ToString(object value)

```
public static string ToString(Object value) {
    return ToString(value,null);
}

public static string ToString(Object value, IFormatProvider provider) { 
    IConvertible ic = value as IConvertible; 
    if (ic != null)
        return ic.ToString(provider); 
    IFormattable formattable = value as IFormattable;
    if (formattable != null)
        return formattable.ToString(null, provider);
    return value == null? String.Empty: value.ToString(); 
}
```

and this is of Convert.ToString(string value)

```
public static String ToString(String value) {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() == value);  // We were always skipping the null check here.
        return value; 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

From this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355736/why-does-convert-tostringnull-return-a-different-value-if-you-cast-null):

There are 2 overloads of ToString that come into play here

```
Convert.ToString(object o);
Convert.ToString(string s);
```

The C# compiler essentially tries to pick the most specific overload which will work with the input. A null value is convertible to any reference type. In this case string is more specific than object and hence it will be picked as the winner.

In the null as object you've solidified the type of the expression as object. This means it's no longer compatible with the string overload and the compiler picks the object overload as it's the only compatible one remaining.

The really hairy details of how this tie breaking works is covered in section 7.4.3 of the C# language spec.