# Not able to figure out exceptions in the below code

Tags: c#

ToUpper() is working when null reference is assigned to an Object type but failing for a null string.
Please clarify the fundamentals of it :

```
Object obj = null;
string str1 = Convert.ToString(obj).ToUpper(); //No exception 

string str2 = null;
string str3 = Convert.ToString(str2).ToUpper(); // Throws exception
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because `Convert.ToString(object)` returns `string.Empty` when `object` is `null` and `Convert.ToString(string)` returns the string unchanged (ie: `null`).
You can not call `.ToUpper()` on `null`.

[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514337/convert-tostring-behaves-differently-for-null-object-and-null-string)