# Why System.Convert(object value) returns String.Empty not NULL when the value is NULL

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I had an issue related to `System.Convert(Object value)` method, my research led me to this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh.aspx). 
I am wondering what are `the reasons`behind this decision that c# team has made, because this doesn't make any sense to me.
From my point of view its better to return "Null", please pay attention to this example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int? ID = null; 
        string result = Convert.ToString(ID);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ,{1}",result ,result.Length);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
//result would be "" and the result.Length=0
```

As  you can see `ID` is `null` but `convert(ID)` is not `null`and it sounds weird to me !!
This is source code of `convert(object value)`I picked it up from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13514470/422627) of the question.

```
public static string ToString(Object value) {return ToString(value,null);}

public static string ToString(Object value, IFormatProvider provider) { 
    IConvertible ic = value as IConvertible; 
    if (ic != null)
        return ic.ToString(provider); 
    IFormattable formattable = value as IFormattable;
    if (formattable != null)
        return formattable.ToString(null, provider);
    return value == null? String.Empty: value.ToString();
```

Please pay attention to the `last line`. I just want to know what is the `rational` behind that.
Thank you in advance.

### Edit

There are so many cases that `ID.Tostring()` is not useful at all
**for example :**

```
public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult MyAction(int? Id)
{
//This line of code dosent show "Id has no value" at all 
MyContetnt = (System.Convert.ToString(Id) ?? "Id has no value");

return Content(MyContetnt);
}
```

In this code example, If you run this Mvc sample through this path :
  [http://localhost: portnumber/ControllerName/MyAction](http://localhost:someportNUMBER/MySite/Home/MyAction) 
I mean `without using ID in the path` You see **Nothing** on the screen because `ID` is `null` here and the resault of `Convert.Tostring(ID)` is `System.Empty` or "" .

I mean in this case there is no way to refactor this code using `null-coalescing-operator`, By using `ID.tostring()` a `nullrefrenceException` would be raised,That is not useful and is not my intention. I know that its easy to say :

```
MyContent = Id.HasValue ? Id.Value.ToString() : "Id has no value" 
// this line works fine;
```

But suppose that The result of `convert.ToString(Null)` was `Null` Then the first code featured with `null-coalescing-operator` would work perfectly.

so I am just curious that  what is the reason behind this idea that the result of 
`Convert.tostring (object null)` is `string.empty` not `null`?

Comment: You can use .ToString() this will raise an error `object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: in your case `string result = (ID).ToString();` will return exception which is `object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: Maybe because null isn't a string, and the authors decided the closest string representation of null was an empty string?

Answer (score 2):

All the `Convert` methods work this way. That's the only reason why you'd use them in the first place.

For example, consider `Convert.ToInt32`. If you pass `null`, you will get `0`. If you don't want that, you can use `int.Parse` instead - that will throw on `null` values.

The same way, `Convert.ToString` is the safe way of getting a string out of any value, including `null`. If you want `null` to throw, you can use `object.ToString()`. You might argue that `default(string)` is `null`, rather than `string.Empty`, but `null` is not a safe value in this sense - you can't work further with `null`, other than by checking for null explicitly. On the other hand, `string.Empty` still allows you to concatenate, or ask for length, or `IndexOf`, or...

The whole point is that the `Convert` class is guarded against `null` values, it goes back to defaults instead. It's not a technical reason, it's there to make (certain ways of) programming easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
return value == null? String.Empty: value.ToString();
```

In your case, value == null so the result will be string.Empty. And it is the same for the method ID.ToString()

```
public override string ToString()
{
  if (!this.HasValue)
    return ""; //return empty string when value is null
  else
    return this.value.ToString();
}
```

But if you want to return null when id is null, write an extension for this.

```
public static class Extension {
    public static string ToStringWithChecking(this int? param) {
        if (!param.HasValue) {
            return null;// or throw exception here
        }
        return param.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I am looking for some technical reasons or design based reasons of such a decision.

Answer (score -1):

The statement in your question is incorrect.
`Convert.ToString(object value)` *does* return `null` when value is `null`. This

```
int? ID = null;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(ID) == string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(null) == null);
object box = ID;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(box) == string.Empty);
```

Writes true true true.

http://ideone.com/jRsefy

In your example, you're not passing `null`, you're passing a reference to a boxed `Nullable` which is `null`.

From the documentation you linked to (I had to read it twice):

> The string representation of value, or String.Empty if value is an
>   object whose value is null. If value is null, the method returns null.

Note: the question did not specify the Framework version, so I assume 4.5.
Apparently the behavior changed from 4.0 to 4.5, so the answer to the question is: they realized it was a bad idea and changed it.

Comment: statement is totally true check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514337/convert-tostring-behaves-differently-for-null-object-and-null-string/13514470#13514470

Comment: @siamak Are you saying `Convert.ToString(null) != null`? Did you check?

Comment: please see my response in the answers part.