# Checking for null value with DataTable.Select

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable.select

I'm using a DataTable select like this:

```
DataRow[] rows = employees.Select("Name LIKE '%" + TB_Search.Text + "%'");

LV_Employees.DataSource = rows;
LV_Employees.DataBind();
```

I have a listview where I'm checking a value that is contained in the datarows that I'm using in the list and I'm checking a value like this:

```
<%# Eval("Title") == DBNull.Value ? "" : Eval("Title") %>
```

But when I do this I still get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.

I tried checking `Eval("Title") == null` as well and got the same error. I'm not sure how else to check for the null values that would fix this issue.

Things I've also tried that still gave the same error:

`(Eval("Title") as string) ?? ""`

`Convert.IsDBNull(Eval("Title")) ? "" : "test"`

`string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Title").ToString()) ? "" : "test"`

`Eval("Title").ToString().IsNullOrEmpty() ? "" : "test"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eval check for DBNull doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224264/eval-check-for-dbnull-doesnt-work)

Comment: I've tried all of those solutions as well with the same error always. So this is different. This seems to be something more related with using the DataTable.Select method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CopyToDataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx) should fix the issue:

```
LV_Employees.DataSource = employees.Select("Name LIKE '%" + TB_Search.Text + "%'")
    .CopyToDataTable();
LV_Employees.DataBind();
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Didn't know about that method (clearly).. hadn't used the DataTable.Select stuff before.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in the codebehind worked, but seems weird that I can't just do the inline check in the markup code.

```
foreach (DataRow r in rows)
{
    if (r["Title"] == DBNull.Value)
        r["Title"] = "";
}
```

Comment: Its not weird, DBNull can't be implicitly cast to string. It's the same problem you would have with anything that cannot be cast to string. Try `... (object)DBNull.Value ? ... `

Comment: `<%# Eval("Title") == (object)DBNull.Value ? "" : Eval("Title") %>` still gave the same error